# jQueryUi datepicker set maxDate and disable subsequent dates

Tags: jquery, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

```
var minDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() -2 , +1); 
var lastDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 0);

$('#datepicker_start').datepicker({
         dateFormat: 'd-M-y' ,
         minDate: minDate,
         maxDate: lastDate,
         onSelect: function(selected) {
              $("#datepicker_end").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)
            }

    });


$('#datepicker_end').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'd-M-y' ,
        minDate: minDate,
        maxDate: lastDate,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
               $("#datepicker_start").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
            }
    });


<b>Start Date</b><input name="start_date" type="text" id="datepicker_start" size="15" readonly>
<b>End Date</b><input name="end_date" type="text" id="datepicker_end" size="15" readonly>
```

I can select any date from current and previous month but how can I set `maxDate` to `31` days from the date selected ?

Tried below to disable the dates less than selected current date.

```
beforeShowDay: function (date) {
var dateString = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
return [selectedDateRange.indexOf(dateString) == -1];
}
```

where `selectedDateRange` contains current month's dates

```
 maxDate: "+30D",
```

How can I set maxDate on jquery ui datepicker to max of 31 days from the date selected using beforeShowDay so that the subsequent dates would be disabled?

**EDIT**

```
$('#datepicker_start').datepicker({
         dateFormat: 'd-M-y' ,
         minDate: minDate,
         maxDate: lastDate,
         onSelect: function(selected) {
              $("#datepicker_end").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)


                    var date=new Date($(this).datepicker('getDate'));
                    day=date.getDate()+30;
                    var month=date.getMonth()+1;
                    var year=date.getFullYear();

                    if(day>31)
                    {
                        day=day-30;
                        month=month+1;
                    }
                    if(month>12)
                    {
                        month=month-12;
                        year=year+1;
                    }
                    newDate=month + "/" + day + "/" + year;

          $("#datepicker_end").datepicker("option","maxDate", newDate);
          $("#datepicker_end").datepicker("option","minDate", date);
            }
    });

     $('#datepicker_end').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'd-M-y' ,
        //minDate: minDate,
        //maxDate: lastDate,
        onSelect: function(selected,inst) {
               //$("#datepicker_start").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
            }
    });
```

It still does not show the dates in disabled mode. Although date values are fetched correct

**CODE UPDATE**

```
$('#datepicker_start').datepicker({
         dateFormat: 'd-M-y' ,
         minDate: minDate,
         maxDate: lastDate,
         onSelect: function(selected) {
                    //code to allow only next 30 days
                    var date=new Date(selected);
                    day=date.getDate()+31;
                    console.log(day);
                    var month=date.getMonth()+1;
                    var year=date.getFullYear();
                    if(day>=31){
                        day=day-31;
                        month=month+1;
                    }
                    if(month>12){
                        month=month-12;
                        year=year+1;
                    }

                    monthVar=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
                    if(day<10)
                        day=0+''+day;
                        newDate=day + "-" + monthVar[month-1] + "-" +  year.toString().substr(2,2);
                    $("#datepicker_end").datepicker("option","maxDate", newDate);
                    $("#datepicker_end").datepicker("option","minDate", date);
        },
    });

     $('#datepicker_end').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'd-M-y' ,
        minDate: minDate,
        maxDate: lastDate,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
               $("#datepicker_start").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
            },
    });
```

`

Comment: Where did `$("#datepicker_end").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)` come from after `onSelect` in `#datepicker_start`!! Did you check the demo I provided in my answer??? Try commenting `dateFormat` once!! and let me know!!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, it works partially when I comment date-format. But how its gonna affect it ? Also it works for dates between two months but not for same month i.e. `1-30 Apr 15` will still show `1-May-15` enabled.

Comment: That I need to check!! Give me some time!!

Comment: Sure, and will it work if I change newDate format to `d-M-y` instead of `4/16/2015`

Comment: Same again I've to test it!! Will try and let you know!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as below:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CkfDP/1558/)**

```
$("#datepicker_start").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
           var date=new Date(selected);
            var max=2;
            day=date.getDate()+30;
            var month=date.getMonth()+1;
            var year=date.getFullYear();

            if(day>31)
            {
                day=day-30;
                month=month+1;
            }
            if(month>12)
            {
                month=month-12;
                year=year+1;
            }
            newDate=month + "/" + day + "/" + year;

          $("#datepicker_end").datepicker("option","minDate", newDate);

        }
});
```

**EDIT:**

```
$("#datepicker_start").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
           var date=new Date(selected);
            var max=2;
            day=date.getDate()+30;
            var month=date.getMonth()+1;
            var year=date.getFullYear();

            if(day>31)
            {
                day=day-30;
                month=month+1;
            }
            if(month>12)
            {
                month=month-12;
                year=year+1;
            }
            newDate=month + "/" + day + "/" + year;

          $("#datepicker_end").datepicker("option","maxDate", newDate);
          $("#datepicker_end").datepicker("option","minDate", date);
       }
});
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CkfDP/1549/)**

**EDIT 2**

The below code works in the format you specified and selecting the beginning dates problem also solved!! The thing is when you set the `maxDate` to `endDate` you should follow the same format as you specified the format in `datepicker`

```
 $("#datepicker_start").datepicker({
        dateFormat:'d-M-y',
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
           var date=new Date(selected);

            var max=2;
            day=date.getDate()+30;
            var month=date.getMonth()+1;
            var year=date.getFullYear();

            if(day>=31)
            {
                day=day-30;
                month=month+1;
            }
            if(month>12)
            {

                month=month-12;
                year=year+1;
            }
            monthVar=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

            newDate=day-9 + "/" + monthVar[month-1] + "/" +  year.toString().substr(2,2);

          $("#datepicker_end").datepicker("option","maxDate", newDate);
          $("#datepicker_end").datepicker("option","minDate", date);
      }
});
```

**[UPDATED DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/CkfDP/1556/)**

**EDIT 3 [Hopefully this is final edit ;)]**

**[UPDATED DEMO 3](http://jsfiddle.net/CkfDP/1559/)**

I was passing `1/Apr/15` format instead of `1-Apr-15` and you can find the changes in the below code!!

```
 $("#datepicker_start").datepicker({
        dateFormat:'d-M-y',
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
           var date=new Date(selected);

            var max=2;
            day=date.getDate()+31;
            var month=date.getMonth()+1;
            var year=date.getFullYear();
            console.log(day);
            if(day>=31)
            {
                day=day-31;
                month=month+1;
            }
            if(month>12)
            {

                month=month-12;
                year=year+1;
            }
            monthVar=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
            if(day<10)
                day=0+''+day;
            newDate=day + "-" + monthVar[month-1] + "-" +  year.toString().substr(2,2);
            console.log(newDate);

          $("#datepicker_end").datepicker("option","maxDate", newDate);
            $("#datepicker_end").datepicker("option","minDate", date);

        }
});
```

Comment: Guru: is it possible to embed this snippet in my existing code ?

Comment: Yes it is!! @Slimshadddyyy.. :) Did you check the demo!! I hope that was what you want to achieve!!

Comment: Guru: It would be great if you could let me know how to embed this in `beforeShowDay`

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy.. Is there any specific reason to put it in `beforeShowDay` because `minDate` for `endDate` can be decided once the date change in `startDate` and that event will be `onselect`

Comment: That will show dates disabled when `end-date` datepicker is selected

Comment: So if am understanding properly you want to disable `30 days` of `endDate` from now at the beginning without selecting `startDate` and when `startDate` is selected disabled `30 days` from `startDate` right??

Comment: Guru: if startdate selected `16-Mar-15` then enddate should be enabled till '15-Mar-15' and rest of the following dates should be disabled

Comment: So you don't want to disable future 30 days!! you want to disable past 30 days from selected date??

Comment: From the selected date, ONLY future `30 days` would be enabled. Subsequent dates would be disabled

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy.. Updated the answer!! kindly check!!

Comment: For DEMO 2, if I select`1-Mar-15` end dates can be selected upto `9-May-15`. Guess its adding more days

Comment: The code seems to be working but for `dateFormat: 'd-M-y' ` i.e. `1-Apr-15`, `var date=new Date(selected);` ouputs `Invalid Date`

Comment: Try `var date=new Date(selected.toUTCString());`

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy.. I just checked but I did not find what you said!! Its is not giving `invalid date`.

Comment: Guru: If I specify ` dateFormat: 'd-M-y'` then `console.log(day);` outputs 'NaN'. `var date=new Date(selected);console.log(date);` gives me `Invalid Date`

Comment: are you saying this happens in **updated demo 3**?? @Slimshadddyyy

Comment: Yes, pls see my Code Update

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy - Check this **[UPDATE](http://jsfiddle.net/Kaushik_Rao/CkfDP/1604/)** I haven't changed anything much except your `start` and `end` date text box ids and commented `minDate` and `maxDate`. But I am getting the date in `console.log`!!!

Comment: `console.log(new Date(selected));` gives me `invalid Date` while `console.log(selected);` outputs `4-May-15`

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy.. Am really unable to get the line which you are saying.. can you paste `console.log` code, add a comment infront of that and update the link and paste it here??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76869/discussion-between-slimshadddyyy-and-guruprasad-rao).

Comment: Guru: Checked in chrome. Its working as expected, but issue is with Firefox. Can we fix this somehow ?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy.. Check the chat!!

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy.. Chatbox!!

Comment: That works, but if I select `31-Mar-15` it allows me to select dates till `21-May-15`. Check here `http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/CkfDP/1613/`

Comment: Guru: Now it does not work when you select `1st APR`